# Closed indicator temporarily disappears after editing closed question

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, closed-questions

Here is my entry for the Lowest-Priority-Bug-of-the-Week Competition:

Sometimes the "[closed]" marker disappears temporarily, after editing the closed question.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Find a closed question, as indicated by the "[closed]" marker after the title.
- Edit the closed question, and hit Save Edits.
- Observe the title of the question no longer has the "[closed]" marker after the title. This is the bug. It should still be present.
- Observe the question is still actually closed, because it has the option to vote for reopen.
- Refresh the page.
- Observe the title now has the "[closed]" marker appended to it.

[image: Repro]

Comment: So this is a problem with the javascript editor not appending the [closed] marker onto the title.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Ah, in that case I should mention: I am using Chrome, and I have a number of popular StackExchange-related userscripts installed.

Comment: I just disabled all my userscripts, and confirmed the problem still occurs.

Comment: just because you disabled your userscripts doesn't negate what I said. It could still be the javascript editor, which is supplied by SEI as part of the page, nothing to do with you.

Comment: @jcolebrand, sorry for being unclear. I did understand that - I didn't intend for my statement to be perceived as a contradiction of yours. Your explanation introduced the risk (at least from the 10,000ft view of the architecture which is all that I have) that some userscript was interfering with the javascript editor, so I wanted to rule that out.

Comment: *(bored me)* added a pic

Comment: I can replicate this, and I am not using UserScripts. The browser I am using is Safari 5.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: @Oddthinking ahhh, I was confused myself. Thanks for the clarification. I hadn't even thought of that, so +2 kudos from me, instead of the +1 you had before sir ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, the question state suffix now works as expected.