# Deleted users get broken gravatar icons in newsletter

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, newsletter

If a user is mentioned in the newsletter as a question asker or answerer, a tiny icon for their gravatar appears.

However, if the user has been deleted, that does not work.

Example from a recent Skeptics.SE newsletter:

> [image]

Looking at the HTML, the source link is empty:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-top: 0;">
        <img src="" align="right" width="18" height="18" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 0; color: #AAA; font-size: 11px;">
       answered by <a href="http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users//user288?newsletter=1&nlcode=58385%7c8169" target="_blank" style="color: #000;">user288</a> 35 votes
    </td>
 </tr>
```

<strike>As you can clearly see, this is a critical bug; the whole SEI team should immediately drop everything to work on this immediately before more people suffer.</strike> Another [entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110481/closed-indicator-temporarily-disappears-after-editing-closed-question) for the Lowest Priority Bug of the Week Competition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sysadmins woke me up at 3 in the morning to fix this bug – I hope you're happy.

It looks like this now:

[image]