# Why does the question's closed status disappear when clicking to load a new edit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, live-refresh

I've come across a small issue which occurs when a question has been closed but the question itself or one of its answers are being edited.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit a closed question. (even closed years ago)
2. In a different tab or browser, edit the question or one of its answers.
3. *"an edit has been made to this post; click to load"* message will appear above the edited post in the first tab/browser, click it.
4. The `.question-status` div becomes hidden, which includes the closed notice below a question and, for a duplicate-closed question, the list of duplicates above the question body. This gives the appearance that the question is no longer closed (until you refresh).

Some screenshots:

> [image: This is definitely closed...]

> [image: Did this magically get reopened?]

I know it isn't common/important but it did confuse me when looking at a particularly bad question - I thought it had been reopened.

Is this an intentional feature? If so, what was the thinking behind it?

---

Another example

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Comment: This very similar thread is a little hard to follow, but since it seems like some people were trying to blame the problem on the user's browser(?).  Really, the discussion just seems to have trailed off...   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110481/closed-indicator-temporarily-disappears-after-editing-closed-question

Comment: @A.M. - thanks for the link. However, that seems to be more about 'closed' disappearing from the title rather than the closed message under the question text being hidden.

Comment: OK, but if both issues they have the same "why" (and they seem pretty similar), we would have an answer to 2 questions.  ...so maybe consider this a 2x bounty on your question.  :)

Comment: Oh, and +1 for pointing out the difference.

Comment: This really should be fixed. It's thrown me off quite a few times.

Comment: @animuson sometimes shiny rep draw better attention than edit, although the free hand circles are magnificent! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took a while to track down, but this is now fixed and will be with you in the next build.

rev 2014.8.01.1737, meta rev 2014.8.01.2407

Comment: Still not fixed for [migrated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238690/an-edit-has-been-made-to-this-post-hides-migrated-banner), is this a trivial fix or should I retract my close vote there and leave it as new bug report?

Comment: Better open a new one. Migration code is not quite "normal" close code...

Comment: Yep, Anna reopened the other one. :)

Comment: @Oded I just had this happen with a [brand new, non migrated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281082/what-is-differ-between-isset-empty#28281171) on SO - possible regression?

Comment: FYI, I [have opened a new report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184642/why-does-the-questions-closed-status-disappear-when-clicking-to-load-a-new-edit) now.