# "An edit has been made to this post" hides migrated banner

Tags: bug, live-refresh, migrated-questions

I don't have idea if it has been already reported, if a post in a question is edited the banner

> an edit has been made to this post; click to load

shows but if i click on it and the question have a

> migrated from x

banner too this will be hidden too.

## Before

> [image]

## After

> [image]

Comment: Closed as a duplicate, but either this is a regression or the original fix described [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184642/why-does-the-questions-closed-status-disappear-when-clicking-to-load-a-new-edit) didn't apply to migrated questions. Reopening.