# "bounty-notification" disappears when loading a newly edited question

Tags: bug, live-refresh, regression

This is a minor issue similar to these other two:

- [Why does the question's closed status disappear when clicking to load a new edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237419/188803)
- [“An edit has been made to this post” hides migrated banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238690/188803)

**When a question with an active bounty has been edited and the viewer does a live refresh of the question, the bounty notification table row disappears.**

Notably, if the question is protected or has some other special status, the `special-status` table cell remains in tact.

### [Example](https://superuser.com/q/793192/83694)

#### Before

[image: screenshot of "Before"]

#### After

[image: screenshot of "After"]

Comment: An identical problem was previously marked as a dupe of that, so I'm confident this is actually a regression.