# Possible regression: Question's duplicate status disappears when refreshing an edited answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, live-refresh, regression

I just experienced the exact symptoms described in [this previously fixed bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184642/why-does-the-questions-closed-status-disappear-when-clicking-to-load-a-new-edit) on a [brand new question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281082/what-is-differ-between-isset-empty).

Note that while the symptoms were the same (the dupe notice disappearing), it happened under slightly different circumstances, in that it was a live, active question with other people editing their own answers, rather than opening a new tab to an old, already closed question.

Reconfirmed the bug on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329498/strange-behavior-using-is-operator-with-strings).  The answer got edited, reloading it caused the notice to disappear.  I used [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a1%20closed%3ayes) to watch for likely instances of it occurring.  Note at the time of writing, that question has 2 reopen votes, but it is/was a duplicate at the time of refreshing the answer.

**Update**

Seems that it's not just happening on duplicates.  I've just witnessed the same behaviour on a question with a Bounty notification banner - reloading a edited answer also causes the bounty notification to disappear.

Comment: I tested the scenario as described in the linked meta post - I can't reproduce it. Do you have any more details?

Comment: Are you sure it was closed as dupe and not something else? (e.g. migrated)

Comment: Definitely.  I was one of the ones that closed it as such

Comment: @Oded Have updated the report - caught it in action again.

Comment: I'll try to repro. Might have to do with answers being added after closure, or answers being edited, or possibly suggested edits being approved after closure. Or having reopen votes... gonna take some digging, this.

Comment: @Oded Great, thanks.  I realise this probably isn't a high priority one...!

Comment: @Oded FWIW, it just happened to me again on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881275/how-do-i-want-the-output-to-be-in-two-decimal-places).

Comment: @Oded And again, on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148592/how-to-access-data-outside-of-then) - definitely reproducible.

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? Just wondering if that might be related.

Comment: @Oded Latest Chrome (it's updated once or twice since I reported this), happens on both Windows 7 and Windows 8

Comment: Any extensions/add-ons/plugins?

Comment: @Oded Nope - I'll try to catch it in a different browser as well

Comment: @Oded Used the search in my question to keep an eye out and have now caught it in Firefox 33, Windows 7 on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149360/check-if-user-exist-php#29149425)

Comment: @Oded As noted in my update, I've just seen this happen on a bounty notification banner too.

Comment: @Oded FWIW, I'm still seeing this happen, and it's been [logged again](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309392/clicking-an-edit-has-been-made-button-on-an-answer-causes-closure-banners-t) over on MSO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was finally able to reproduce reliably and fix it.

With you in the next build.