# Question titles showing up as "undefined"

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, title

Recently, the titles to some questions have been displaying as `"undefined"`:

[image]

`"undefined"` is replaced with the question's true title upon refreshing the page. Is this a bug?

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I don't know what happened to my edit. The system just decided to roll that paragraph into my edit when it was already there. Filing bug report right now.

Comment: No, no no. *I didn't add that paragraph*. There was a bug in the system. I only edited the tags and nothing else. The paragraph was already there. I have no idea why the paragraph was rolled into my edit.

Comment: Linky? (bananas)

Comment: @AmericanLuke I realized what you were saying after I wrote my comment (hence my deleted comment).  Best guess since that it was within the 5 minutes grace period, was an edit collision with the OP.  I've had my own suggested edits attributed to the OP in similiar situations before, but never seen the opposite.

Comment: @doubleDown It seems to be occurring randomly (and not very frequently).

Comment: I think it's somewhat related to that feature. Someone said it's been reported before, so I'm trying to find that. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116725/192187

Comment: It happened to me too.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it by editing a post in a question and canceling it, working on it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was the bug-fix for [Closed indicator temporarily disappears after editing closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110481) causing this one.
It will be fixed in the next release...

Comment: -1 for [answer plagiarism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188377/187824).