# Question name changes to "undefined" when canceling answer edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

It seems that when I cancel a edit of my answer the subject of the question changes to `undefined`.

Steps I did:

1. Open a question where I have answered: [Add Values to Existing Entry in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585507/add-values-to-existing-entry-in-dictionary) (question subject is "Add Values to Existing Entry in Dictionary")
2. Click on `edit` for my answer (Clicking `edit` on question does not show this bug for me)
3. After the `edit` screen is opened - click on `cancel`
4. See "Undefined" question subject:

[image]

I was trying this in Chrome 28, Windows 7SP1.

Comment: See [Question titles showing up as “undefined”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188322/question-titles-showing-up-as-undefined)

Comment: I don't seem to have this problem. Browser info?

Comment: Managed to reproduce this as well. Chrome 28.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was the bug-fix for [Closed indicator temporarily disappears after editing closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110481) causing this one.
It'll be fixed in the next release...